# Visual Studio debugger can't login to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, authentication

I have a simple EF Code First project that has to create a database in my local SQL server if it doesn't exist. However, when I try to debug my application I get the error:

```
Cannot open database "<Database>" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\someone@me.com'.'
```

I somewhat understand that because I login to Windows with my Microsoft account. 
So I changed my connection string from using integrated security to username and password.

I made sure the user is created on the SQL server (Login & sysadmin rights) but it still fails when I debug in Visual Studio.

So..... I build the project and ran the application directly via the exe file and everything works. But I want to understand why it doesn't work with the debugger.

Have I missed something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem.

My local Windows account was paired with my Microsoft account. For some reason Visual Studio sends my Microsoft account to the SQL server to authenticate even when run under specific local credentials.

My solution was to create anew local user on my workstation with NO assosiated MS account. 
I made the account member of Administrators and gave it permission to the SQL server then everything was fine...

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the server and database name are specified correctly in connection string. I had a typo, and got the error.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that the debugger runs with different credentials (or could be set to do so). Especially if your account is not admin.

Maybe this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greggm/2008/05/15/visual-studio-remote-debugger-service-user-account-requirements/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it seems like the debugger runs under different credentials but even when I try to run VS as admin or with different credentials, I get the exact same error message. I will look into the service credentials later and see if that solves the problem